# google+ button displaying an error message

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to use a g+ button so I wrapped the  in an another div in order to customize the foreground image that let the true g+ button appear when hovering, but the click on the button displays a red triangle.

Here's the code :

```
<div class="btn" style="background:  url(./img.jpg) no-repeat;">
<div class="position">
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="none" data-href="{$url|escape:'url'}"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

(the 'position' div ensures the right positioning of the foreground image)

Then I thought it was a problem of url : so I suppress it to let the default one be called. It still didn't work so I suppressed the wrapping divs, and I still have the same message. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where we can see this problem occurring?

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually occurs when you don't have a proper domain name.If you url is something like this `106.168.11.5/quest` then the google plus button will not work and will behave as you said.